# how do I look an array to extract data

Tags: php, arrays, database, foreach, while-loop

Hi all Im trying to query a database and store the results ($searchResults[]) as an array :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['indexSearchSubmit']))
{
foreach($_POST['industryList'] as $selected)
    {
        $_POST['industryList'] = $selected;
        $locationListResults = $_POST['locationList'];

        $results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM currentListings 
WHERE location = '$locationListResults' AND industry = '$selected'");

        $searchResults = array();

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
            {
                $searchResults[] = $row['industry'];
                $searchResults[] = $row['location'];
                $searchResults[] = $row['title'];
                $searchResults[] = $row['description'];
            }

    }
                mysqli_close($con);
}

?>
```

the problem im getting is when I try to echo the result:

```
<?php 

echo $searchResults[0];

?>
```

its only bringing back 1 result not displaying all the results in the arrray as i want it to.

Could anybody please point out what it is im doing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
<?php 
print_r($searchResults); // Prints all array elements
?>
```

Alternatively, you can make use of a **`for`** loop to **`echo`** all elements too..

```
foreach($searchResults as $k=>$v)
{
 echo $v;
 echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the reply as youcan tell im a bit new, what does th k=>v represent?

Comment: It represents the keys and values in the array.

Comment: When using the foreach method it is showing all 4 fields that im trying to display but only once not showing all 4 fields for each result if that makes sense?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question ?

Comment: using the foreach i need it to show 2 results from the database that match the original query and each result has 4 fields which are : industry,location,tite,description but im only gettting 1 result

Answer (score 0):

Your code puts your data into 1D array. You probably want sth else so instead of this:

```
$searchResults[] = $row['industry'];
$searchResults[] = $row['location'];
$searchResults[] = $row['title'];
$searchResults[] = $row['description'];
```

do this:

```
$tmp = array();

$tmp['industry'] = $row['industry'];
$tmp['location'] = $row['location'];
$tmp['title'] = $row['title'];
$tmp['description'] = $row['description'];

$searchResults[] = $tmp;
```

or just this (thanks to Barmar):

```
$searchResults[] = $row;
```

This way you store your data as 2D array. So every row you obtain remains in one subarray.

To print the row (which is now in 2D array) iterate over subarrayw:

```
foreach($one_of_searchResult_rows as $k => $v)
{
    // do whatever you need with $k and $v
}
```

Comment: Or simply `$searchResults[] = $row;`

Comment: This still doesn't solve the problem with `echo $searchResult[0]`, which is his question.

Answer (score 0):

Lets make it simple :

```
$serach_result=mysqli_fetch_all ($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
//you should use print_r while trying to print an array
print_r($search_result[0]);
```

Reference : [mysqli_fetch_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a 2d array. Try this code snippet :

```
$searchResults = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
        {
            array_push($searchResults,$row);
        }
```

This should push each row as an associative array in every cell of your final searchResuts array. You could then access the values like:

```
echo $searchResults[0]['industry']; //and so on
echo $searchResults[0]; //Should print out the first match/row of the sql result
```